# Gitlab API filter projects by topic (project tag)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm in trouble filtering projects by "tag" with the api (named topics in project settings).

I would get the same result as the following UI query https://gitlab.xxxxxx.com/explore/projects?tag=ruby

It returns all project that are tagged with the "ruby" topic.

Here is an example of result I have with the api when describing a single project:

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer $GITLAB_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.hostname.com/api/v4/projects/42?simple=true" | json_pp
...
"tag_list" : [
  "ruby"
],
...
```

According to the documentation (https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#list-all-projects) I should be able to filter on project tag_list using topic parameter

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer $GITLAB_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.hostname.com/api/v4/projects?topic=ruby&simple=true" | json_pp
```

But this query returns all my projects, even those without any tag or the wrong ones

I tried using "tag" or "tag_list" instead of "topic" but nothing worked as I expected

Is someone have an idea on how to proceed ?

Note that I'm using gitlab CE 13.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, you're using gitlab version 13.9 and the ability of filtering projects by `tag_list` or `topic` has come with version 14 and later.

See:
https://docs.gitlab.com/13.11/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects

Comment: Indeed, I didn't check the right version of the doc, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: using the new API topics.

See [GitLab 14.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/11/22/gitlab-14-5-released/#manage-project-topics-with-the-api) (November 2021)

> ### Manage project topics with the API
>
> In this release, thanks to [Jonas Wälter’s](https://gitlab.com/wwwjon) contributions, adding topics in project settings is easier than ever.
>
> In addition to the latest project topic management features in the UI, you can now use the API to retrieve topics by list or ID.
>
> We’ve also made it possible for administrators to create or edit topics through the API. This introduces full parity between project topic management in the UI and API.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/topics) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/345788).

[Listing projects assigned to a topic](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/topics#list-projects-assigned-to-a-topic) is still done through the [project API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects), though.
But the API around topics is now more complete.

That API also includes, with [GitLab 14.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/03/22/gitlab-14-9-released/#api-endpoint-to-delete-project-topics) (March 2022):

> ### API endpoint to *delete* project topics
>
> In a previous release, we added the ability to create and manage project topics that are used to categorize projects and find similar new projects. However, we did not create a way to delete them.
>
> In this release, thanks to [Timo Furrer](https://gitlab.com/tuxtimo)’s contribution, we added an API endpoint to delete project topics to make topic management more neat and efficient.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/topics.html#delete-a-project-topic) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/353360).